# how do you prove the existence super natural

Tags: metaphysics, metaphilosophy, time

How can you prove the existence of super-natural being ?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what this question is aimed at, but maybe have a look at different proofs of the existence of God, such the [Cosmological](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cosmological-argument/), [Teleological](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/teleological-arguments/), and [Ontological](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/) argument.

Comment: Seems like we get this question quite often. I'll try to answer it anyway.

Comment: If you mean prove by some sort of scientific endeavor, you cannot prove it. By definition it is 'super' natural which means beyond the sensual realm. We can only prove those things that are part of the sensual realm. One can make logical arguments to prove it but not what is considered scientific evidence.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is for the being to write "I am here" in large letters half way between Earth and the Sun in a language that everyone on the planet can contemporaneously understand. Even if they're blind.

Failing that, you can attempt a bit of linguistic sleight of hand to convince people. See @MarkOxford's comment for the types of arguments that have been made historically.

Whether or not these constitute proof is generally in the eye of the beholder. I would argue that, in pretty much any other field that has the concept of proof (maybe with the exception of the law?) they would not. But I have no proof of that...